# Django REST displayed filtered nested resource

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to return JSON in a simple GET that includes a row from a joined table. The models:

```
class School(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(max_length=18,primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False)
class Meta:
    db_table='school'


class FKTable(models.Model):
school = models.ForeignKey(School,blank=False, db_column='school_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
class Meta:
    db_table='fk_table'
```

And the serializer:

```
class SchoolListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.CharField(source='id')
name = serializers.CharField(source='name')
fkColumn = ???? 
class Meta:
    model = models.School
    fields = ('id','name','fkColumn')
```

The problem is I want to also filter the nested resource that I join against on the 'name' column so I don't know what to put for 'fkColumn' in the serializer. In SQL it would look something like this:

```
SELECT school.*, fk_table.value from school INNER JOIN fk_table on
 fk_table.school_id = school.id AND fk_table.name = 'some name'
```

The end result JSON I want is:

```
{
"schools": [
    {
        "id": "someId",
        "name": "someName",
        "fkColumn": "Value"
    }]}
```

RelatedField does not seem to work and none of the documentation seems to give a solid answer on how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Revised after clarification. Define an fkeySerializer:

```
class fkeySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   ...
```

Then link this in your main serializer:

```
fkey = fkeySerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
       model = models.School
       fields = ('id','name','fkColumn',)
```

---

You can use a MethodField serializer here. For example:

```
fkColumn = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_fkColumn(self, obj):
    return obj.fkColumn

class Meta:
   model = models.School
   fields = ('id','name','fkColumn',)
```

---

As an aside, perhaps there's a good reason for it, but it might be easier to rename this table to be more easily readable

Comment: This does not quite meet what I'm looking for because this is a one-to-many relationship, and thus there is a set of rows from 'fkColumn' and I just need to get one of them based on the value from one of the columns.